# Trying to write a program that checks the number of characters in each string in a list

Tags: python, for-loop, nested

```
def friend(x):
    new_name_list = []
    for each_name in x:
        name_count = 0
        for each_char in each_name:
            name_count += 1
        if name_count == 4:
            new_name_list.append(each_name)
    print(new_name_list)
```

I'm trying to complete a codewars problem which is as follows: "Make a program that filters a list of strings and returns a list with only your friends name in it.

The name has to have exactly 4 letters in it.

Ex: Input = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Jason", "Yous"], Output = ["Ryan", "Yous"]"

I've created the program above which seems to run fine in PyCharm and work for each list I test it with. However when I check it with codewars it keeps giving me an error message. Not too sure what I'm doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message you face?

Comment: You know you can use `len(each_name)` to get the length of a string.

Comment: Also, if the instructions say *return* a list, then you're not doing what the instructions say. Printing is not returning.

Comment: although you should use len instead of looping to get the length of each name, your code works fine for me...make sure you are pasting it into codewars properly and indentation isnt being screwed up

Comment: Fixed with simply changing the print statement to return, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

could also just use a basic list comprehension:

```
[name for name in Input if len(name)==4]
```

or even use compress from itertools:

```
from itertools import compress
mask = [len(name)==4 for name in Input]
list(compress(Input,mask))
```

output:

```
['Ryan', 'Yous']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```py
def friend(x):
    print(list(filter(lambda name: len(name)==4, x)))
```

or

```py
def friend(x):
    names_to_print = []
    for name in x:
        if len(name) == 4:
            names_to_print.append(name)
    print(names_to_print)
```

If you want to return only, just replace print statement with return.

Comment: Your first solution will not print what you expect in Python 3. Your second example is equivalent to `[name for name in x if len(name) == 4]`, which is the recommended alternative to `filter` (it's debatable, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Learning python and trying to solve the same problem. I wrote the code below and would like to find out how to move-on following "my logic" way.

It seems that it adds just the very first item to the `new_friends` list and not iterating over all the elements of `x` list.

Beside above, the return value is giving back > `None` ... what is the thing I'm not noticing here?

```
def friend(x):
    x = ["Ryan", "Kieran", "Jason", "Yous"]
    new_friends = []
    for str in x:
        if len(str) == 4:
            return new_friends.append(str)
    return new_friends[0:]
```

Instead of if statement I also tried a nested while loop .. but no success adding other items to the `new_friends` list.

Thank you so much for your answers ;)